# How to concatenate smaller matrices to form a larger matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I would like to concatenate 14641 number of 3X3 matrices into a matrix of size 363X363 and the large matrix must contain 121 submatrices in each row(121*3=363 columns) and 121 such rows of submatrices(121*3=363rows).I have gone through the similar questions but I didn't get the correct logic to concatenate large number of matrices.
Awaiting your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

PS: I got those 3X3 matrices from a 363X363 matrix. The following code is for splitting the single matrix into submatrices.

```
I=imread('photo.jpg');
B = randi([0 255],363,726,3);
B(1:numel(I)) = I;
L=B(1:363,1:363);
[al,bl]=size(L);
ImageSize=al*bl;
BlockD=3; % i assume 3x3 block
BlockSize=BlockD*BlockD;
TotalBlocks=ImageSize/BlockSize;
subL=zeros(BlockD,BlockD,TotalBlocks); %arrays of blocks.
LL=double(L); 
k=1;
for i=1:BlockD:al
 for j=1:BlockD:bl
    subL(:,:,k)=LL(i:i+BlockD-1,j:j+BlockD-1); 
    k=k+1;
 end
end
```

Now I want to concatenate all these 'subL' submatrices to form 'LL' again

### Using blocproc instead of above code

I tried using blockproc function instead of the above code. I did this piece of code and is working pretty well.Thank you

```
I=imread('photo.jpg');
B = randi([0 255],363,726,3);
B(1:numel(I)) = I;
L=B(1:363,1:363);
q=[1 2 3 4];
fun=@(block_struct)quaternionrotate(q,block_struct.data);
LL = blockproc(L,[3 3],fun);
```

and the function quaternionrotate is

```
function [ Lrot1 ] = quaternionrotate(q,A)
 qinv=quatinv(q);
 B=zeros(3,1);
 A1=[B A];
 Lrot=quatmultiply(q,quatmultiply(A1,qinv));
 Lrot(:,1)=[];
 Lrot1=Lrot;
end
```

Comment: Please **don't** tell me all of these matrices are stored individually as separate variables....

Comment: Since you very sensibly have your matrices in a `3x3x14641` matrix, it's just a matter of reshaping to a `363x363` matrix. You'll just need to tell us what order the `3x3` matrices are stored in. If, by chance, you *haven't* stored these sensibly, you're in a world of hurt.

Comment: I would suggest adding the relevant information from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495752/how-to-divide-a-363x363-image-into-submatrices-of-3x3-size-and-each-submatrix-mu)

Comment: That was rather a good idea @excaza. I am editing the question right now.

Comment: @beaker I want them to be arranged as [m1 m2..m121; m122 m123...m242; m243... ...m14641];

Comment: "getting errors" is not very descriptive. Perhaps you could tell us what the error is and where it occurs.

Comment: Those errors were because of the size mismatch in the function which I've rectified later and now the output is pretty clear without any errors. I will edit the code right now. @beaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out!

```
% I used this to make 14641 3x3 sample matrices, you should use your own

matrix = ones(3,3);
for i = 2:14641
   matrix = [matrix, i*ones(3,3)]; 
end

c_size = 121;

output = cell(c_size, c_size) % Make 121x121 cell matrix

% Populate the cell matrix
for i = 1:1:c_size
    for j = 1:1:c_size
        output(i,j) = {matrix(1:3, (i-1)*c_size*3+(j-1)*3+1 : (i-1)*c_size*3+(j-1)*3+3)};
    end
end
```

This breaks up the 43923x3 size matrix of 363 3x3 matrices into a 121x121 cell matrix of 3x3 matrices. Now that's a tongue twister...

Either way the code does what you need! :)

Comment: It might be worth your while also looking into MATLAB's "reshape" command? If you restructure your data it could prove useful.

Comment: Yeah @dean_sh, but I am trying it with blocproc because a function has to be performed on each submatrix. Thanks

Comment: To access the data in each submatrix use:

**output{cell_row,cell_column}(row_number,column_number)**

You can then perform an operation on the cell. Or just use **output{cell_row,cell_column}** to grab the data in the 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Thanks again @dean_sh I got that.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck it!